# Cache query result for REST API calls

Tags: codeigniter

I have a rest API in codeigniter version 3.
I have a very large and complex database.
Querying very slow. So, I want to cache the result of these queries.
How to do this in codeigniter?

I tried to enable caching from Database.php in config folder. But it doesn't work.
What if table is updated. Please suggest me a better way.

Comment: i can't understand your question

Comment: Really? I made a call to, say, `all-news/singlenews/132`. Here 123 is news ID. I fetch the result from the database in codeigniter.  It gave me result and I returned it as JSON to client. But it's slow. everytime it fetches for same request. I want to cache the query result.

Comment: please update your code in the question